# When I use Vite in vanilla Js instead of using webpack and when I try to run the project in dev and prod it renders everything twice

Tags: javascript, vite

When I use Vite in vanilla Js instead of using webpack and when I try to run the project in dev and prod it renders everything twice.
The code works fine when I use webpack but when I use Vite it renders every div two times.